# Issue including page.php on page

Tags: php

I am trying to include a vbijreizen_kaart.php within some code. When I put it outside of the echo, but within the loop (i think this is correct terminology). It will load my google map, however, it will not bring back the rest of the results in my (while) results. When I remove it, the results appear, so I'm doing something wrong but I just don't know what.

The bit of code that is where I am having problems is:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php include('vbijreizen_kaart.php');?>
<?php
echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th width='20' valign='top'><div align='left'>&nbsp;</div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height='1' colspan='9' valign='top' bgcolor='#333333'></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
echo "<td bgcolor='$row_color'>" .date("d-M-Y H:i", 
strtotime($row['vertrekdatum2'])). "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='../flags/".$row['countryflag']."'>
&nbsp; <abbr title=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['luchthavennaam'])."\">
".$row['luchthavencode']."</abbr></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='$row_color'><img src='../flags/".$row['countryflagaankomst']."'>
&nbsp; <abbr title=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['aankomstnaam'])."\"> 
".$row['aankomstluchthaven']."</abbr></td>";
```

I have tried doing just

```
echo "<br />";
echo include('vbijreizen_kaart.php');
echo " blah blah blah
```

and I've tried as above, and nothing will let me display the map that exits on vbijreizen_kaart.php as well as the data that would display in the while results.

I can verify in Toad that I have the Query working as it should.

Comment: Close echo `" blah blah blah";`. Do you see ` blah blah blah` on your page? If not, `die()` or `exit()` has probably occurred, on `vbijreizen_kaart.php`.

Comment: hi PHPglue. Yes, I do see the data that would be where i put blah blah blah on the page.

Comment: I ended up just making 3 pages into total (index.php, child1.php and child2.php) and using <?php include('child1.php') ?> and same for child2, which does the job.

Answer (score 1):

`include` is not a method, so syntax can look like: `include 'vbijreizen_kaart.php';`, but that's not the problem. `include` basically allows you to access the classes, functions, and variables that are on the `include`d page. You don't `echo` or `print` the `include`d page itself, but rather the classes, functions, and any variables on the `include`d page. Also, the `include`d page can `echo` or `print` to the page you `include` it into, so it could be a matter of position.